# Save image from URL by paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, upload, paperclip

Please suggest me a way to save an image from an URL by Paperclip.

Answer (score 156, accepted):

Here is a simple way:

```
require "open-uri"

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :picture

  def picture_from_url(url)
    self.picture = open(url)
  end
end
```

Then simply :

```
user.picture_from_url "http://www.google.com/images/logos/ps_logo2.png"
```

Comment: If you need to use `update_attributes` rename `picture_from_url` to `picture_url=(value)` for example.

Comment: This is potentially insecure because a user could call `user.picture_from_url('/etc/password')`. It's probably fine in most situations though.

Comment: For security, you should whitelist the URI's scheme and blacklist private hosts

Comment: See answer below for even better solution.

Comment: Using `open(url)`, the filename is not accurate, e.g. `open-uri20150106-10034-lpd5fm.` instead of `ef3a601e_ef3d008b_ef3d0f7e.jpg`.

Comment: @joshuaPinter use `URI.parse(url)` instead of `open(url)`

Answer (score 202):

In Paperclip 3.1.4 it's become even simpler.

```
def picture_from_url(url)
  self.picture = URI.parse(url)
end
```

This is slightly better than open(url). Because with open(url) you're going to get "stringio.txt" as the filename. With the above you're going to get a proper name of the file based on the URL. i.e.

```
self.picture = URI.parse("http://something.com/blah/avatar.png")

self.picture_file_name    # => "avatar.png"
self.picture_content_type # => "image/png"
```

Comment: From paperclip wiki: https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/wiki/Attachment-downloaded-from-a-URL   I successfully run it in console, the app is in heroku.

Comment: FYI, for S3 urls I still get `application/octet_stream` as the `content_type`.

Comment: If you are still using paperclip after it's deprecation, you may need to also ensure the URI IO loader gets loaded: Paperclip::UriAdapter.register   (in the config, or temporarily via the console if that's all you need)

Comment: The approach is correct but in last version the sintax is changed! Check out my answer below => https://stackoverflow.com/a/56039191/3182171

Comment: You need to add entry in initializer https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/wiki/Attachment-downloaded-from-a-URL

Answer (score 18):

It didn't work for me until I used "open" for parsed URI.
once I added "open" it worked!

```
def picture_from_url(url)
  self.picture = URI.parse(url).open
end
```

My paperclip version is 4.2.1

Before open it wouldn't detect the content type right, because it wasn't a file. It would say image_content_type: "binary/octet-stream", and even if I override it with the right content type it wouldn't work.

Comment: Thanks for this!  Exactly what I was missing myself.

Comment: You will lose your exension if you do this. You need Paperclip::UriAdapter.register in the initializer.. then you don't need .open at the end. See https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/wiki/Attachment-downloaded-from-a-URL

Answer (score 15):

First download the image with the `curb` gem to a `TempFile` and then simply assign the tempfile object and save your model.

Comment: I don't see what's wrong with this answer, voting it up 'cause I'm seeing a down vote.

Comment: This is the most performant answer ([by far](http://toevolve.org/2011/04/03/http-request-performance.html)). I am not really a performance-geek, but this really adds up if you are working w/ large files.

Answer (score 8):

Into official documentation is reported here https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/wiki/Attachment-downloaded-from-a-URL

Anyway it seems not updated, because in last version of paperclip something has changed and this line of code is no more valid:

```
user.picture = URI.parse(url)
```

It raise an error, in particular this error is raised:

```
Paperclip::AdapterRegistry::NoHandlerError: No handler found for #<URI:: ...
```

**The new correct syntax is this one:**

```
url = "https://www.example.com/photo.jpeg"
user.picture = Paperclip.io_adapters.for(URI.parse(url).to_s, { hash_digest: Digest::MD5 })
```

Also we need to add these lines into **config/initializers/paperclip.rb** file:

```
Paperclip::DataUriAdapter.register
Paperclip::HttpUrlProxyAdapter.register
```

Tested this with paperclip version `5.3.0` and it works.

Comment: Thanks for this - the config stuff fixed it for me (Paperclip v6.1.0)

Comment: Thanks, Diego, this is workin also well the PaperClip v6.0.0

Answer (score 3):

It may helpful to you. Here is the code using paperclip and image present in remote URL .

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'open-uri'
require 'paperclip'
model.update_attribute(:photo,open(website_vehicle.image_url))
```

In model

```
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :photo, :styles => { :small => "150x150>", :thumb => "75x75>" }
end
```

Answer (score 3):

As those are old Answer's here's a newer one:

**Add Image Remote URL to your desired Controller in the Database**

```
$ rails generate migration AddImageRemoteUrlToYour_Controller image_remote_url:string
$ rake db:migrate
```

**Edit your Model**

```
attr_accessible :description, :image, :image_remote_url
.
.
.
def image_remote_url=(url_value)
  self.image = URI.parse(url_value) unless url_value.blank?
  super
end
```

*In Rails4 you have to add the attr_accessible in the Controller.

**Update your form, if you allow other to upload an Image from a URL**

```
<%= f.input :image_remote_url, label: "Enter a URL" %>
```

Comment: what is the `super` for?

Comment: The function `super` is used to invoke the original method, searching of the method body starts in the super class of the object that was found to contain the original method

Answer (score 2):

This is a hardcore method:

```
original_url = url.gsub(/\?.*$/, '')
filename = original_url.gsub(/^.*\//, '')
extension = File.extname(filename)

temp_images = Magick::Image.from_blob open(url).read
temp_images[0].write(url = "/tmp/#{Uuid.uuid}#{extension}")

self.file = File.open(url)
```

where Uuid.uuid just makes some random ID.