# Feed Aggregator in Rails which can grab image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, aggregation, rss

Im newbie. What Feed Aggregator available in Rails which can grab one image (largest image) from the source URL?

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand your question

Comment: means it import one image from the source URL and store it in our server.. so that we can use that image as thumbnail along with our aggregated contents

Answer (score 0):

You could:

- parse the feed with SimpleRSS
- get the picture's url
- store the image with the method described here (using paperclip):

[Save image from URL by paperclip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4049709/save-image-from-url-by-paperclip)