# Which is the proper way to upload an image from an external url with Paperclip on rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip

I want to download to a MOdel the image from an url:
I already read [Save image from URL by paperclip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4049709/save-image-from-url-by-paperclip)
but 
first I run into this error:

```
    Paperclip::Error: Page model missing required attr_accessor for 'picture_file_name'
```

afterwards
, I added the attr_accessible parameter and run into this other error:

```
    RuntimeError: `attr_accessible` is extracted out of Rails into a gem
```

I now added also the protected_attributes to no success.. This is how my model is reading right now:

```
require 'open-uri'
class Page < ActiveRecord::Base
has_attached_file :picture

#Get the picture from a given url.
def save_picture_from_url()
    self.picture = URI.parse(self.image_url)
end
end
```

SOLVER

I found my own solution. THe errors were do to proceeding without reading Paperclip's guide.

Firstly I had to install imagemagick

Secondly I had to add a migration for the model Page to add the attachment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my own solution. THe errors were do to proceeding without reading Paperclip's guide.

Firstly I had to install imagemagick

Secondly I had to add a migration for the model Page to add the attachment