# how to save image from url in paperclip rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, open-uri

how to save image from url in paperclip rails?

and i have model article :

```
require "open-uri"
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessible :feed_id, :url, :name, :author, :image, :image_caption, :text
has_attached_file :image, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" }, :default_url => "/images/:style/missing.png"

def picture_from_url(url)
  self.image = URI.parse(url)
  self.save
end

def self.add_articles       
      article = create!(
        :feed_id => 1,
        :name => "test",
        :author => "udin",
        :image_caption => "test caption",
        :text => "bla..bla..bla",
      )

 image_url = "http://img.antaranews.com/new/2013/10/big/20131030047.jpg"
      article.picture_from_url(image_url)
    end
  end
```

how to make the image url save to my public folder?

Comment: if i try open(image_url) using open-uri, the image just save to tmp... how to save the image file to public?

Comment: related to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4049709/save-image-from-url-by-paperclip

Comment: i want save the image file from url to my local directory @marvwhere

Answer (score 2):

fix my problem using gem minimagick

```
file = MiniMagick::Image.open(image_url)
save_to_local = file.write  "public/assets/file_name.jpg"
```