# Rails: How to upload image from URL to S3 through controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3

I'm trying to find a way to import an image from URL to Amazon S3 without using a client-side hack (jQuery). It looks like Paperclip doesn't allow for uploading from a URL.

Comment: Paperclip doesn't allow for this, but [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4049709/save-image-from-url-by-paperclip) is a clever hack.

Comment: @jmera thank you, that looks like it will work!