# Updating a model's avatar through a link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I use Paperclip for a model's avatars. In a view of the model I show a list of images, and I would like to be able to change the model's avatar by clicking on one of those images.

The [2nd answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4049709/save-image-from-url-by-paperclip) works well in order to update the avatar, but how can I execute it inside a link?

Comment: The furthest I've got is this link: `<%= link_to "Update", {:action => :update_avatar, :id => @artist.id, :url => i.url}, :method => :put %>`  with this route `put '/artists/:id/update_avatar/:url' => 'artists#update_avatar', :as => 'update_avatar'`. The controller `update_avatar` also exists . The error this is throwing is no mathing routes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it myself. I just updated the route to

```
put '/artists/:id/update_avatar' => 'artists#update_avatar', :as => 'update_avatar'
```

and then changed the link to

```
<%= link_to "Update Avatar", {:action => :update_avatar, :id => @artist.id, :url => i.url}, :method => :put %>
```