# How can I upload paperclip image on remote server (accessed by pem file) rails console?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip

I am having production server and database is from `aws`. I visit remote machine using pem file & start `rails console`.

I have particular invitee (from `Invitee` model) & have following column to store image using `paperclip`

**invitee.rb**

```
  has_attached_file :profile_pic, {:styles => {:large => "640x640>",
                                         :small => "200x200>", 
                                         :thumb => "60x60>"},
                                   :convert_options => {:large => "-strip -quality 90", 
                                         :small => "-strip -quality 80", 
                                         :thumb => "-strip -quality 80"}
                                         }.merge(INVITEE_IMAGE_PATH)
```

I want to upload image at https://i.stack.imgur.com/PBVCX.jpg by using `rails console production`. How can I do this?

Input I can have is, image url and object of invitee for which `profile_pic` columns to be updated.

I have image in my local machine but I cannot upload it from local to remote so using https://imglur.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to check another answer ["Save image from URL by paperclip
"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4049709/save-image-from-url-by-paperclip) which does what you want to achieve. Check [code snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4050758/1826279): `self.profile_pic = open(url)` will upload the picture to your model. Your picture real URL is https://i.stack.imgur.com/umhSI.png

Comment: I tried for `URI.parse` but got some issues `open-uri` is pretty handy.